# Invoking :hover pseudo-class by transferring events via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Here is the scenario:

You have two images and they are stacked on one another. The highest-order z-indexed image is responsible for handling click events (think Google's Map API) and is transparent, while the image below is responsible for a visual representation.

Here is a pseudo-HTML/CSS representation:

```
div.visual-container {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}

div.visual-container:hover {
    background-color: #555;
}

div.click-container {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}

<div class='lowest'>
    <div class='visual-container'></div>
</div>

<div class='highest'>
    <div class='click-container'></div>
</div>
```

Now, when the 'highest' element is clicked, the event is dispatched also on the 'lowest' element.

The basic idea:

```
function onHoverEventForHighest() {
    createMouseEvent(lowest_element, 'mouseover', event);
};
```

This part is fine and transfers the event accordingly, **but it does not seem to invoke the :hover CSS psuedo-class.**

Has anyone had any luck with doing something of this nature?

Comment: What exactly doesn't invoke `:hover`? Mousing on to the top-most element? Or are you expecting it to propagate to the bottom-most? Also, is there a specific browser you're having troubles with?

Comment: Creating a DOM event 'mouseover' and invoking it on the desired element does not invoke the element's :hover CSS pseudo-class. There isn't a specific browser.

Comment: So, yeah, basically it is not propagating in the way I want it to. It does call the mouseover event, but it does not invoke :hover.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `:hover` pseudo-class is not necessarily known for its reliability. Also, there's no way (that I know of) to control its behaviour via Javascript.

According to the [W3C's spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/events.html#event-mouseover), the `:hover` pseudo-class should only be applied when the **user** initiates the action. Quote:

> The :hover pseudo-class applies while
>   the user designates an element (with
>   some pointing device), but does not
>   activate it. For example, a visual
>   user agent could apply this
>   pseudo-class when the cursor (mouse
>   pointer) hovers over a box generated
>   by the element. User agents not
>   supporting interactive media do not
>   have to support this pseudo-class.

So, your best best, in this situation, would be to apply a concrete class (let's say `.hover`) via a function bound to the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events of the desired target elements.

As an aside, you could probably save yourself a lot of hassle if you were to re-structure your markup into a hierarchical/nested form, then the DOM would automatically bubble these events for you. That said, [see this SO question and answer on how to manually propagate mouse events through absolutely positioned elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009753/pass-mouse-events-through-absolutely-positioned-element).

Answer (score 1):

Jason's element-nesting comment inspired this:

```
<style type="text/css">
div.visual-container {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}

.widget-container:hover div.visual-container {
   background-color: #555;
}

div.click-container {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}
</style>
...
<div class="widget-container">
  <div class='lowest'>
    <div class='visual-container'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='highest'>
    <div class='click-container'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This may have been the solution Jason was hinting at. As he said, the DOM doesn't give you control over pseudo-classes, but you don't need the DOM for this. Style-y solutions for style-y problems.

Comment: Yes, that's one way to approach it. But, what I actually had in mind was that if you ad `visual-container` inside of `click-container` he wouldn't have to manually propagate all his DOM events, like he is--and `:hover` would still work too.

Comment: Yeah, that comment minus the typos. :)