# Adding hover trigger from another div

Tags: jquery, hover, triggers

I am trying to activate the native hover effect of a div from another div. I understand that I could do this all in jQuery and add the styles in there, but would rather leave the native `:hover` in the CSS. I'm just wondering if there is a way for this to work:

```
$("#div1").live("mouseenter", function() {
  $("#div2").trigger("mouseenter");
});
```

I'd like to call it by doing something like this, but it isn't working. Is there really no way to trigger an event from another element's event?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is

```
$("#div1").live("mouseenter", function() {
  $("#div2").mouseenter();
});
```

Comment: No luck :( I think that event takes arguments

Comment: @jakeprzespo: When `jQuery#mouseenter()` is used without arguments, it’s an alias for `jQuery#trigger('mouseenter')`.

Comment: @jakeprzespo: not necessarily.

Comment: Oh, ok. Will keep that in mind. Still isn't triggering correctly however.

Answer (score 0):

This should work?

```
$("#div1").mouseenter(function() {
  $("#div2").mouseenter();
});
```

Comment: Live binds the events staticly to content even if the content is being changed (ajax)

Answer (score 0):

This have been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283054/invoking-hover-pseudo-class-by-transferring-events-via-javascript/1283072#1283072)

> according to the W3C's spec, the :hover
>   pseudo-class should only be applied
>   when the **user** initiates the action.
>
> The :hover pseudo-class applies while
>   the user designates an element (with
>   some pointing device), but does not
>   activate it. For example, a visual
>   user agent could apply this
>   pseudo-class when the cursor (mouse
>   pointer) hovers over a box generated
>   by the element. User agents not
>   supporting interactive media do not
>   have to support this pseudo-class.