# Simulate hover using JavaScript events

Tags: javascript, events, hover

Is it possible to simulate hover using JavaScript Events? I tried injecting mouseover event on the target element but no luck.

For example, if there is a link that has a hover selector, is it possible to "hover" over it using JavaScript Events? Basically, I want to trigger CSS hover. You can assume I can't use jQuery.

Comment: You could add a css class called "hover" and add it or remove it as needed, just style it exactly like the hover. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1283072/1217408

Comment: Do you mean triggering the css-hover styling via javascript?

Comment: You can take a look at this here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608788/css-hover-vs-javascript-mouseover

Comment: Yes, I want to trigger CSS hover using JavaScript Events only. You can assume I can't use jQuery.

Comment: @bellpeace Do you mean you want to trigger the native hover action or do you want to trigger handlers attached to it?

Comment: It would help to know **why** you want to do this, as the "best" answer could be different. e.g. if all you want is to get the style applied dynamically w/o actually mousing, then simply toggling a *hover* class as @TheZ suggests is the most straightforward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jQuery hover event is just using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events. Here is the source of jQuery's hover:

```
function (fnOver, fnOut) {
    return this.mouseenter(fnOver).mouseleave(fnOut || fnOver);
}
```

Comment: How cross browser these events are? It seems that is supported by FF from version 10.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would simply add onMouseOver and onMouseOut events to the element in question

Like this:

```
<div class="something" onmouseover="hover(this);" onmouseout="unhover(this);">
```

Then make your javascript change the element's class (if you want two different CSS classes) or simply modify the element's style directly.  You could do something like this.

```
<script>
function hover(element) {
    element.setAttribute('class', 'something hover');
}
function unhover(element) {
    element.setAttribute('class', 'something');
}
</script>
```

Please note that you can also use a library like jQuery to handle this even more simply.

Comment: I already have an element with hover CSS applied. I want to trigger that hover event by using JavaScript.

Comment: @bellpeace I have added some javascript to the example.

Comment: I think you missed my point. I am not crafting the page (i.e., the page can be random), I just want to simulate hover using JavaScript events.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, CSS hover event is more convenient than just binding these two events `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. So it'll need a little more efforts, which are:

1.Clone the element

2.Add a listener to mouseenter event

3.Recursively redo step `1`,`2` and restore the cloned element on mouseleave

Here is my working draft.

```
function bindHoverEvent(element,listener){
    var originalElement = element.cloneNode(true);
    element.addEventListener('mouseenter',listener);
    element.addEventListener('mouseleave',function(){
        bindHoverEvent(originalElement,listener);
        this.parentNode.replaceChild(originalElement,this);
    });
}
```

Please note that, `cloneNode` does not copy event listeners, so you need to manually rebind events to the cloned element and all its children yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to simulate hover using JavaScript events. 
I created a module for swapping out  images on hover. You can experiment and adapt the module to fit your needs. For the example, I made the image paths and DOM selection elements generic.

```
// module for swapping out images on hover 
var imageSwap = (function ModuleFactory() {

    "use strict";

    var imageContainer = document.getElementById("image-container"),
        image = document.getElementsByClassName("image")[0],
        imageSource1 = 'path/to/your/image1',
        imageSource2 = 'path/to/your/image2';

    function handleImageSwap(e) {
        if (e.target.id === "image-container") {
            image.setAttribute("src", imageSource2);

            e.target.addEventListener("mouseleave", function _handler_() {
                image.setAttribute("src", imageSource1);
                e.target.removeEventListener("mouseleave", _handler_, false);
            }, false);
        }
    }

    function init() {
        imageContainer.addEventListener("mouseenter", handleImageSwap, false);
    }

    var publicAPI = {
        init: init
    };

    return publicAPI;

})();

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", imageSwap.init(), false);
```