# Is there any way to simulate mouse over to a particular x/y offset on particular element using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mouseevent, offset, mouseover

I need to click at an x,y offset of an image. How do I do it using Javascript?

Comment: The title of your post says `mouse over` (hover) but your question asks about `click`.  Tha's a litle bit confusing.  Here is a good source for information about simulating hover: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728406/simulate-hover-using-javascript-events

Comment: There is a example in this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createEvent

Comment: @karthick: I tried this $(document.elementFromPoint(315, 270)).click();

Comment: @DavidTansey: I need to click at x/y offset.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can refer this too. [jquery trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, you will not be able to move to some x,y and click. You can only simulate event using createEvent. You can find the documentation here.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createEvent

Comment: Thanks, Sinduja! Will try it!

Answer (score 0):

There are always so many methods to fulfill 1's requirement. But its always important to pick the best one.

In your case what I interpret is, you want to call a JS function with params as X & Y coordinates. And if you want some specific X, Y values then why you want to simulate click / hover event when you can directly call the JS with static coordinates values.

Comment: You are right Amit but, I am using it for an automated testing tool where providing the function wouldn't be an appropriate options for the testers who will not know about whats in the code.

Comment: so you want to trigger click event from automated testing tool like selenium. Event than you have to specifically write the code to click on the HTML element.