# hover effect php not working

Tags: php, yii, hover

Hi there i'm working on an project, and everything in this project is written in the yii framework. I'm already pretty far, but at some point im stuck, I searched on Google alone could not find anything about this. That is why I ask your help!

In the code below, I need to apply a hover effect. The code is written in php and the yii framework.

```
        $_SESSION['Active'] = $_GET["Share"];
    if (isset($_GET["Share"])){ 
    $sharepanel = array('src' => $sImageURL.'share1.png',
    'alt' => $clang->gT("Share panel"), 
    'title' => $clang->gT("Share panel"),
    'height' => 35,
    'width' => 35,
    'style' => 'margin-left:5px');
```

Comment: you can't apply `hover` effect in `php`

Comment: So how can i make this possible then?

Comment: `javascript` or `css`

Comment: Do all things with php bad idea. Create css class, append it to element and work with them in css. css/js inline code is bad in most cases.

Comment: I understand, but i need to write it with this code because the whole template is written like this, i need to customize a already written template

Answer (score 0):

I would use CSS for this. With something like the following.

```
img:hover {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Not too sure how supported `:hover` is for the `<img>` tag though.

Comment: And before write `img{ border: 1px solid transparent }`

Comment: Pseudoclasses was problem only in IE6 ;)

Answer (score 0):

According to

> i need to customize a already written template

You may write shitty code like

```
<div class="something" 
    onmouseover="this.setAttribute('style','border: 1px solid yellow;');" 
    onmouseout="this.setAttribute('style','border: 1px solid transparent;');">
text
</div>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11728590/1346222

Use at your own risk. With disabled JS this will not work

```
$sharepanel = array(
    'src' => $sImageURL.'share1.png',
    'alt' => $clang->gT("Share panel"), 
    'title' => $clang->gT("Share panel"),
    'height' => 35,
    'width' => 35,
    'style' => 'margin-left:5px; border: 1px solid transparent;',
    'onmouseover' => "this.setAttribute('style','border: 1px solid yellow;');",
    'onmouseout' => "this.setAttribute('style','border: 1px solid transparent;');",
);
```