# Capture mouse events on hidden/occluded text area

Tags: html, text, canvas, clip

I want a circular text area in the canvas so what I am doing is placing the text area behind the canvas like so

```
<textarea cols="40" rows="20" name="textArea" id="textArea">
    Inside
</textarea>
```

then using more or less the following code to create a 'hole' in the canvas so the text can be seen

```
ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
ctx.fillRect(0,0,500,500);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(250,250,250-5, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
```

And, if anyone finds it useful, here is the CSS code I am using

```
canvas {
    border: 0px solid yellow;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
}
textArea {
    border: 0px solid yellow;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1; 
    color: orange; 
    background-color: blue; 
    border-width: 0px; 
    text-align: center; 
    font-size: x-large
}
```

Then, I obviously change the padding so the text appears circular. Everything works, except the text area is not capturing any events (mouse click, motion, key press..), which is understandable. My question is how do I turn those events on.

Comment: `textArea` should just be `textarea`, unless you meant that to be an `id` selector, in which case tack a `#` prefix and leave it as is.

Comment: sorry that was an `id` selector. Is the `#` required, or just a better naming convention?

Comment: @puk The `#` is required if you are using an `id` selector.

Comment: @alex: I believe you, but I just tried all four variations `textArea`, `textarea`, `#textArea`, and `#textarea` and all had the exact same effects.

Comment: Can you set up a http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate this please?

Comment: @puk The only reason it worked is because `textarea` on its own will select `textarea` elements. If you had > 1 then it would select every one and apply the CSS to all of them.

Comment: ok, and ok, let me set up a jsfiddle example

Comment: I have never used jsfiddle, so this is the best I could come up with.
http://jsfiddle.net/pukster/2zmDX/

Comment: @puk The canvas is always going to be overlaid for that effect to work, so click events will be caught by the `canvas`.

Comment: @alex: Is there no way to activate elements behind other elements? Can't I manually pass the signals as you suggested below?

Comment: @puk I am trying it now.

Comment: @alex: I don't know if this helps, but here is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009753/pass-mouse-events-through-absolutely-positioned-element

Comment: @puk You could try that technique.

Comment: @alex: It is not working. I keep getting errors such as `onclick of object #<an HTMLDIVElement> is not a function`

Comment: @alex: I think the problem is in how I am trying to pass the signal to the text area. the following does not work `canvas.onfocus=function() {document.getElementById('textAreaDiv').focus();}` because there is no `focus()` function yet.

Comment: @alex: I'm almost on the verge of giving up. Even if I manage to send the signals via `document.createEventObject` I have no guarantee that the textarea will behave as desired. I think it's easier if I implement a limited text editor in the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you have the `canvas` above the `textarea`, in which case, events are being captured by the `canvas`.

You could send them to the `textarea` manually but this will be problematic. Some will be easier, however...

```
document.getElementById('my-canvas').click = function() {
    document.getElementById('textaArea').focus();
}
```

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of that. I will be manually managing these things, to check to see when the user is inside the circle and when he/she is outside of the circle.

Comment: Well I just tried that, with not only onfocus, but keypress, and it does not seem to work. Any other suggestions?