# Overlay Div That Can Be Clicked Through

Tags: javascript, html, css, opacity

I was wondering if there is a way using css or javascript that allows for a semi-transparent div element to appear visually on top of all other elements, but hyperlinks and other interactive elements under it can still be clicked?  Just a whimsical idea to give my website the ability to darken or lighten the look of the website.

EDIT

I know that z-index moves objects from the background to the foreground but they also block interactive objects...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such behavior possible via `poiner-events:none` (non-standard and not supported by IE).
Originally being an SVG feature, it's supported for any SVG element (IE 9+):

```
<svg poiner-events="none">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.5" />
</svg>
```

But for the effect you mentioned I would recommend to use opacity on `body` and some background on `html`:

```
body {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

html {
  background: black;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009753/pass-mouse-events-through-absolutely-positioned-element

Answer (score 0):

create another div element on top of existing div, and have it's z-index more than the existing one. Hope this should help.