# "pointer-events: none" does not work in IE9 and IE10

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

The CSS - property `pointer-events: none;` 
works fine in Firefox, but it does not in Internet Explorer 9-10.

Is there a way to achieve the same behaviour of this property in IE? Any ideas?

Comment: If your intention is to restrict the user from clicking anywhere on the page during an ajax call, you can use: **$('body').css({'cursor':'wait'});**, and when you want to return to normal cursor state, use: **$('body').css({'cursor':'default'});**

Comment: Feb. 2017: FYI  it works on IE11.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From the MDN docs:

> Warning: The use of pointer-events in CSS for non-SVG elements is experimental. The feature used to be part of the CSS3 UI draft specification but, due to many open issues, has been postponed to CSS4.

[Read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events), basically, `pointer-events` on a non-SVG (Scalable Vector Graphic) is non-standard.
If you check the browser support table on the linked page (about two-thirds down) you'll note that IE support on non-svg's is *ziltsh*, *jack squat*, *naut*,... not supported, that is.

After some digging, I did come across [this article](http://www.vinylfox.com/forwarding-mouse-events-through-layers/) that does allow for you to mimic the behaviours through use of layers, and , thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855135/css-pointer-events-property-alternative-for-ie), I found [this JS-bin](http://jsbin.com/uhuto/1/edit) That might help...

However, in IE (and Opera, and AFAIK all browsers), you could simply force a type of cursor on an element:

```
a, a:hover, a:visited, a:active, a:focus /*, * <-- add all tags?*/
{
    cursor: default;/*plain arrow*/
    text-decoration: none;/*No underline or something*/
    color: #07C;/*Default link colour*/
}
```

The result should be pretty similar to that of `pointer-events: none;`

*Update:*

If you want to prevent the click events in IE that, as shasi pointed out, is prevented in other browsers, simply add an event listener that delegates the click event.
I'll assume, at the moment, that you're targeting all `a` elements:

```
var handler = function(e)
{
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a')
    {
        if (!e.preventDefault)
        {//IE quirks
            e.returnValue = false;
            e.cancelBubble = true;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
};
if (window.addEventListener)
    window.addEventListener('click', handler, false);
else
    window.attachEvent('onclick', handler);
```

That should prevent all click events on anchor elements.

Comment: But this still does not prevent click event on the link in IE.

Comment: @Shasi: This question is about the CSS pointer-event rule. CSS doesn't prevent click events either

Comment: No, the CSS rule "pointer-events: none;" does prevent click event on an element, in Firefox & Chrome. It does not work in IE though. [Here is a Demo](http://davidwalsh.name/demo/pointer-events.php)

Comment: @shasi: Added a small JS snippet that takes care of business

Comment: This is still not the same as `pointer-events: none`. If there's a clickable element *under* the `<a>`, it won't receive the click event. If the `<a>` has `pointer-events: none`, the underlying element would receive the event.

Comment: @cheeesus has an important point. I need a polyfill that will send the click to any elements under the clicked element (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009753/pass-mouse-events-through-absolutely-positioned-element). Anyone know of a solution?

Answer (score 6):

For crappy IE10, there is another solution, example :

```
/* must be over the element that have the action */

.action-container:after {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 250; 
    background-color: grey; /* must have a color on ie10, if not :after does not exist... */
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Awesome fallback suggestion! Thank you :)

Comment: .action-container should have `position: relative`. Nice anyway.

Answer (score 4):

From looking at the APIs, I don't think Rich Harris' Points.js, nor [Hands.js](http://handjs.codeplex.com/), provide support for *pointer-events: none*.

Thus, I just implemented a tiny script to polyfill this feature:

- [Pointer Events Polyfill](https://github.com/kmewhort/pointer_events_polyfill).

Comment: The pointer events API is not the same as the pointer-events CSS property.

Comment: This polyfill doesn't work in IE10. I tested on bing maps

Comment: Why require jQuery for a polyfill?!

Comment: @reid If anyone of you young'ns are truly wondering why, it was made in 2013 and jQuery was more than not used in many projects.