# jQuery 1.10.2 selector broken in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

This basic jQuery click intercept doesn't seem to work in IE with jQuery 1.10.2:

HTML

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="/test">simple selector</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function (){ 
    $('#nav a').click(function (e){
          e.preventDefault();
          alert("intercepted test link");
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YfRMR/6/ (it's jQuery 1.10.1 on JSFiddle, but I'm seeing the same effect on my dev site).

Works in Chrome, Safari, FF. Doesn't work in IE9 or IE10. It *does* work in IE if I revert to jQuery 1.9.x

Am I missing something or is jQuery 1.10.2 failing here?

Comment: Oh wait - I think it might be a problem with JSFiddle. I'm getting `'$' is undefined` when I choose 1.10.1

Comment: seems to work with 1.10.2 http://jsfiddle.net/YfRMR/10/

Comment: that's very odd... i don't see anything in the source for IE that would cause it. I'm getting "Access Denied", but it's not an http vs https problem, and the code is in the header not the body,

Comment: @Ade yes i get this error in opera and ie too with 1.10.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the JSFiddle problem was a red herring. The above code does appear to work in IE10 in normal circumstances, outside of JSFiddle.

The problem I had (in the non-stripped down original markup) was that there was a second hidden UL on top of (in terms of z-index) my link, hidden using:

```
opacity: 0;
pointer-events: none;
```

However IE10 doesn't support pointer-events [for non SVG elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441810/pointer-events-none-dosnt-work-in-ie-9-and-ie10) so the click was hitting the hidden element above in IE.

I would use `display: none;` but this prevents a CSS opacity transition from taking place, unless you introduce a delay with JavaScript (which I will now, wearily, do).