# Imagemap with overlying div: Mouseover disappears on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, imagemap

Could anyone give me a hint how to solve this?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9Br6h/

Have a look at the part left under... with the flag. On the area the mouseover is visible.. but it disappears on the flag - that is the thing I want to remove. It should stay visible.

But please keep in mind that this is a very simple example. In real I've tons of areas and flags. ;o)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // add div for showing dates
    $('body').append('<div id="mo_termin"></div>');
    // show div on mouseover
    $('area').mouseover(function(event) { 
        var left = event.pageX + 30;
            var top = event.pageY + 5;
            display = '<div class="views-field-field-body">Keine Termine</div>';
        $('#mo_termin').css({top: top,left: left}).html(display).show();
    });
    $('area').mouseout(function() {
        $('#mo_termin').html('').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the css property `pointer-events: none;`as well.

```
#karte .flag {
      pointer-events: none; /*Added line*/
    position: absolute;
    background: url('http://static.netzwelt.de/farcade/images/capturetheflag1.gif') no-repeat;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 200px;
    left: 50px;
}
```

Here is the Demo http://jsfiddle.net/9Br6h/2/.

Comment: Note that `pointer-events` doesn't work for most versions of IE (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441810/pointer-events-none-dosnt-work-in-ie-9-and-ie10)).

Comment: I hate IE ^^ - but the solution is nice.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the flag completely covers the 'hover' area underneath it, you can modify your code so that the line that sets the `mouseover` event reads as follows:

```
// show div on mouseover
$('area, .flag').mouseover(function(event) {
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/9Br6h/1/

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work in the real case - as there is much more JS .. concerning the content of the overlay.. which is generated by data-fields of the area.