# Pointer Events and Opacity is not working in IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

This is the HTML code:

```
<div id="opac">

<ul id="nav" style="font-size:75%" >


    <li><a  href="javascript:void(0)">Menu</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a  href="javascript:void(0)" id="BGSRU01">BGSRU01</a></li>
            <li><a  href="javascript:void(0)" id="BGSRU02">BGSRU02</a></li>
            <li><a  href="javascript:void(0)" id="BMSRU06">BMSRU06</a></li> 
        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>

</div>

<div id="display"></div>
```

**This is Javscript script code calling the css properties:**

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    function click_function(){

        var ajax_load = "<img id='loading' src='loader.gif' alt='loading...' />";

          $("#display").html(ajax_load)

        $("#opac").css({"opacity":"0.5"});

          $("li").css({"pointer-events":"none"});

         $("ul").css({"pointer-events":"none"});
 }

});

</script>
```

Onclick of the button the indicator image will load and the menu ul and submenu li will kept the **'opacity'-'0.5'** so that it becomes blur and **'pointer-events' as 'none'** so that the user cant do any action this works in the **chrome** and **mozilla** but in the **IE10** is not working

The user can do actions on the menu and submenu in **IE10**, but in **chrome** and **mozilla** works fine.

pleas suggest me how to make work in **IE10**

Comment: [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) is supported only in  [>= IE11](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: please share the other code in javascript with css code to disable the user actions.

Comment: Check out Elias answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441810/pointer-events-none-does-not-work-in-ie9-and-ie10/17441921#17441921

Comment: what about the opacity...?

Comment: opacity is supported in all IE Versions http://caniuse.com/css-opacity

Comment: but its not working in IE10 but works fine in  Chrome and Mozilla

Answer (score 1):

pointer-events is not supported in IE10

Comment: Than how to make it work in IE10, is there any javascript library to add or  please suggest with other code in css property in javascript to make disable of the user actions.

Comment: please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855135/css-pointer-events-property-alternative-for-ie

Comment: what about the opacity..?