# Basic CSS - how to overlay a DIV with semi-transparent DIV on top

Tags: css, html

I'm struggling to make this render right in my browser (Chrome). I have a wrapper holding all the elements of the HTML, and I want to have a DIV (lets call it div-1) that hold a image, and has a overlay div on top of it to the left, like I sketched in this picture...any quick solutions?

[image: div bg with overlay semi transparent div]

Answer (score 172):

Here's a pure CSS solution, similar to DarkBee's answer, but without the need for an extra `.wrapper` div:

```
.dimmed {
  position: relative;
}

.dimmed:after {
  content: " ";
  z-index: 10;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

I'm using rgba here, but of course you can use other transparency methods if you like.

Comment: @marcvangend the solution works but if there is a scrollable div instead of the image can we still allow the scroll to work?

Comment: @Onkar You can try adding `pointer-events: none;` to the `.dimmed:after` selector. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009753/pass-mouse-events-through-absolutely-positioned-element. Please let us know if it works in this specific use case.

Comment: Fantastic. If you want to click through to the underlying element, add the rule

pointer-events: none; 

to the after element css rules

Answer (score 33):

Using CSS3 you don't need to make your own image with the transparency.

Just have a div with the following

```
position:absolute;
left:0;
background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
```

The last parameter in background (.5) is the level of transparency (a higher number is more opaque).

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VsHyD/)

Answer (score 17):

```
.foo {
   position : relative;
}
.foo .wrapper {
    background-image : url('semi-trans.png');
    z-index : 10;
    position : absolute;
    top : 0;
    left : 0;
}

<div class="foo">
   <img src="example.png" />
   <div class="wrapper">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Might want to add `top:0; left: 0;` to the `.wrapper`

Comment: Thats true. Changed it

Comment: Also, if the image isn't already transparent, `opacity:0.4;
filter:alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */`

Comment: PS - is using rgba not advisable, I see you went with transparent png...this is due to internet explorer, right?

Comment: Yes, to support older browsers which can't handle CSS3

Answer (score 14):

For a div-Element you could just set the opacity via a class to enable or disable the effect.

```
.mute-all {
   opacity: 0.4;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Like the answer previous, but I'd put ::before, just for stacking purposes. If you want to include text over the overlay (a common use case), using ::before will should fix that.

```
.dimmed {
  position: relative;
}

.dimmed:before {
  content: " ";
  z-index: 10;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```