# How do I merge two transparent png files in Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, image-processing, imagemagick, ionic-framework

I have two transparent png files with identical width and height in my cordova/Ionic app. I wish to combine the two png files into a new png file of the same width and height with one file overlayed on top of the other file. i.e., one image is a layer on top of another image. The result must be a transparent png. How can I do this in my javascript cordova app?

Comment: this sounds eerily similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859993/basic-css-how-to-overlay-a-div-with-semi-transparent-div-on-top, don't worry about cordova, just use html, css, and javascript

Comment: No actually I want to output the result as a transparent png file which I will save in the documents folder of the cordova app. The question you referenced was more about displaying the merged result. I don't care as much about the displaying.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by adding both images to a canvas that you create on the fly, or have in your DOM but not displayed, then read back the canvas by using the canvas' toDataURL("image/png").  Use the 2d context on the canvas to load the images in.

Something like:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'); // or create one just don't display it
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var image1 = '<image url>';
var image2 = '<image url>';
var image = new Image();
var compositeImage;

image.src = image1;
ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

image = new Image();
image.src = image2;
ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

compositeImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

compositeImage then has a data URL of your composite image that you can use to do whatever with.