# How to leave a div and an image over a carousel?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, frontend

I want to make a carousel and over it, a div and then to give that effect to be superimposed.
Try to make as this [EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gtw7375/jdbzqyaL/), but without success. When I add such properties (`absolute and relative`) the code of the carousel it does not.

[image]

My DIV Overlay => `id="faixa"`

The slide in background shaped carousel. The green div and logo superimposed on the carousel.

I tried something like:

```css
#myCarousel{
 position: absolute;
}

#fixa{
 position: absolute;
 width: 20%;
 height: 400px;
 background: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  </ol>

  
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    
    <div id="fixa">
   DIV QUE SERÁ SOBREPOSTA
    </div>
    
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.savoir.com.br/cea.com.br/imagem/cadastrocqlv/imagem/cadastrocqlv-53440.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://www.asia-turismo.com/imagens/asia-imagem.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

How to make this?

Comment: Are you looking for something of this sort?  https://jsfiddle.net/bbb0uwk0/ Also check this for reference. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859993/basic-css-how-to-overlay-a-div-with-semi-transparent-div-on-top

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `z-index` for `#fixa` to stack this div on top of the carousel. Also note that z-index works only with positioned elements(position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed - you are already covered here):

```
#fixa{
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 10;
 width: 20%;
 height: 400px;
 background: black;
}
```

See [fiddle](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGZQJE).

Answer (score 0):

As a small point, note that the z-index is applied to the **`<div>`**, and not to the `<img>` tag.

I had the same question of wanting to position an image within a div on top of a carousel.

*(Not enough karma to comment on KrisD's answer above)*

Answer (score 0):

Just put `div` and `image` in `carousel-caption`. I came here to find the same answer and this worked for me.

```
<div class=carousel-inner>
<div class=carousel-caption>
image and logo here
</div>
```