# how to remove the hover property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have written a function to calculate the xpath of any element in my chrome extension. But i am facing an issue on few websites.
There are few websites like [this page](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/apple-macbook-air-13-3-display-intel-core-i5-4gb-memory-128gb-flash-storage-silver/1581921.p?id=1219056464137&skuId=1581921) where when i hover over the element it adds a class to the element and the element i am getting by click event Listener is generating xpath which includes those extra classes. is there a way to get the element when its not hovered over by mouse ?
content page :

```
document.addEventListener('click', function xyz(e){
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
//alert(e);
var target = e.target || event.srcElement;
var attributes = Array.prototype.slice.call(target.attributes).map(function(i)    {
    return [String(i.name)+": "+String(i.value)]
})
alert(attributes);
//prompt("xpath1 :",getPathTo(target));
getPathTo(target);
for(i=0;i<xpathList.length;i++)
{
    prompt("xpath",xpathList[i]);
}
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method:"captureElement",data:attributes});   
},true);
```

Comment: Add a transparent overlay to the page that doesn't let clicks through, then when that overlay is clicked have your script detect what target was clicked from the x and y coordinates using document.elementFromPoint(x, y) (first disable your overlay so elementfrompoint cant tell you the element that was clicked).

Comment: how to achieve this ?

Comment: You can start by learning css and html.  I'll give you a few hints, but you have got to learn to figure it out on your own.  Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859993/basic-css-how-to-overlay-a-div-with-semi-transparent-div-on-top , look up z-indexes, learn how to use the z-index property and you should be good.  If your overlay doesn't work, just ask another question and we will help you, but you need to have written your code and html first.