# How to set css overlay top of the div elements

Tags: html, css

I have created an overlay class:

```
.overlay {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

So I want to set this class in any div box element to show overlay while ajax busy.

```
<div class="overlay" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid red;margin: 3px;" >
  <div style="width: 150px; height: 100px; border: 3px solid greenyellow;background-color: indianred; margin: 30px;" >
    <input type="text" value="this is box"/>
    <button>This is button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or

```
<div class="overlay" style="width: 150px; height: 100px; border: 3px solid greenyellow; margin: 30px;" >
  <input type="text" value="this is box"/>
  <button>This is button</button>
</div>
```

But, the div elements are on top of the overlay.

[Working code](https://jsfiddle.net/vgz0u6wb/2/) is here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Basic CSS - how to overlay a DIV with semi-transparent DIV on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859993/basic-css-how-to-overlay-a-div-with-semi-transparent-div-on-top)

Comment: As your divs are children of the overlay and you have only set a background to the overlay, the child divs will always be on top of the background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:before` pseudo for this:

```css
.overlay {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.overlay:before {
   content: "";
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay" style="width: 150px; height: 100px; border: 3px solid greenyellow; margin: 30px;" >
  <input type="text" value="this is box"/>
  <button>This is button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

```css
.overlay {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.overlay:before {
   content: "";
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay" style="width: 150px; height: 100px; border: 3px solid greenyellow; margin: 30px;" >
  <input type="text" value="this is box"/>
  <button>This is button</button>
</div>
```