# Overlay for modal dialog in Internet Explorer not preventing hover

Tags: css, internet-explorer, angularjs, z-index

I have a simple modal dialog that when opened adds an overlay to the page via AngularJS.

```
var $mask = angular.element('#tbxContainerMask').length
                                    ? angular.element('#tbxContainerMask')
                                    : angular.element('<div id="tbxContainerMask"></div>').css({
                                        width: angular.element(window).width(),
                                        height: angular.element(document).innerHeight(),
                                        display: 'none'
                                    }).appendTo('body');
```

This works as expected in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and Safari.

```
 #tbxContainerMask {
     position:absolute;
     left: 0;
     top: 0;
    z-index: 10090;    
 }
```

The modal has a slightly higher zIndex of 10100. All good and dandy until we come to Internet Explorer. The overlay shows as does the popup, but the user is able to hover over areas of the page and make menus popup and hover effects are triggered. None of the other browsers do this. How can I make IE (I'm using version 10, but need to support 8 & 9 as well) behave like the other browsers? I want the overlay to not allow the hover events on the items "under it". Basically behave as what I would call "expected". Thanks for any help. I was hoping to avoid some type of handler that would capture mouseenter on the overlay and either stop propagation or call blur() on the overlay etc... I actually did try that but it didn't appear to work. Any ideas?

Comment: I realize this doesn't help since caniuse.com says this isn't supported in IE till 11 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009753/pass-mouse-events-through-absolutely-positioned-element but I think you probably want to search outside of angularjs and do some experimenting with some more vanilla JS and HTML code to simplify the problem.

Comment: Add `opacity: 0`, if an element has `transparent` background color, the elements behind are accessible. Though looks like you already know this...

Comment: @Teemu - That worked perfectly! Thank you.

Comment: @NLV Remember, this works in IE only, other browsers still detect the element. You can also use CSS, set `pointer-events: none` to the element to drop it off from detectable elements.

Comment: @Teemu - In my case chrome and edge worked as expected with transparent background except IE. With opacity set to 0 all three browsers worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is odd, but it seems to work just fine. I added opacity and filter as well as a color to the css rule and then IE behaves as expected. I tried setting the color to transparent and it didn't work either. Perhaps applying color sets some sort of context in Internet Explorer. I don't know.

```
#tbxContainerMask {

    position:absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10090;
    opacity: 0.1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=10);
    background: #fff;

}
```