# Overlap span with image

Tags: css, z-index

I'm having trouble overlapping a countdown and buttons with [Skull and crossbones](http://cliparts.co/cliparts/8c6/8RG/8c68RGrzi.png). `z-index:` doesn't seem to be working. (I Don't have the reputation to post an image.)

I'd like the picture to be visible once the countdown is negative, and flash every other second.

How can I get the skull and crossbones to overlap it all?

jsfiddle.net/2Lufxs2t

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>
    <title>Countdown</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
   var seconds = 10;

function stopTimer() {
    clearTimeout(countdownTimer)
}

function floor(x) {
    return x | 0;
}

function pad(n) {
    if (n < 0) {
      n = -n;
    }
    if (n < 10) {
        return '0' + n.toString();
    }
    return n.toString();
}

function secondPassed() {
    var minutes = pad(floor(seconds/60));
    if (seconds < 0) {
        minutes = '-' + minutes;
    }
    var remainingSeconds = pad(seconds % 60); 

    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
    if (seconds > 0) {
        seconds--;
        if (seconds > 8) {document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green"; }
        else if (seconds == 5) {document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";}
        else if (minutes == 0 & seconds == 0) {document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";}
    }
    else{
    seconds--;

        //if (seconds == 0 || seconds == 2 || seconds == 4 || seconds == 6 || seconds == 8 ) {document.getElementById("Image1").style.visibility= "visible";}
        //else {document.getElementById("Image1").style.visibility= "hidden";}
    }
}
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload = "getSeconds()">
    <div ="wrapper">
    <span id="countdown" style="color:black; font-size: 500px; font-weight: bold"></span>

    <button onclick="countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000)">Start</button>
    <button onclick="stopTimer()">Stop</button>

            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server"  ImageUrl="\\scnas1\dev\vbdev\Time\skull.gif"
             />&nbsp;
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>

#Image1 
{
    z-index:0;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
#countdown
{
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Comment: it will be better.if you create jsfiddle demo for your problem so that we can help you in efficient way

Comment: @SachinKadam How do you use an image with JSFiddle? I'm new to it.

Comment: you can not upload image to jsfiddle directly but you can use third party uploader like http://postimage.org/. then use URL given by them in jsfiddle

Comment: @SachinKadam Buttons work on my machine but not jsfiddle, sorry. I'm not sure why that is. http://jsfiddle.net/3e2egof6/1/

Comment: jsFiddle only understands plain HTML, not server side languages like ASP so you have to put the rendered code in there, like `<img id="Image1" src="http://s15.postimg.org/es5w3xpob/skull.gif" />`. Also, where's the code for `getSeconds`?

Comment: @j08691 I was posting something more specific, but I edited and delivered all the sauce :)

Comment: I still see no code for `getSeconds`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2Lufxs2t/ <-- potentially working JSFiddle, but as the others mentioned, you need to include the getSeconds function if it exists, if it doesnt, remove the onload call

Comment: Might be easier to just explain what you're trying to make. As it looks like it could be highly over complicated at the moment if you just want a counter with start/stop over the top of an image.

Comment: Sorry, there is no getseconds function.

Comment: Are solutions using [CSS3 backgrounds and borders](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/) (draft candidate Sep 2014) acceptable? I was able to get a flashing skull under the buttons using background, but it won't work in some older browsers

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you're aiming for.

But I've provided an example of what i THINK you might be after

```js
var startBtn       = document.getElementById('start'),
    stopBtn        = document.getElementById('stop'),
    timerEl        = document.getElementById('timer'),
    secondsPassed  = 0,
    secondsTimer   = null,
    updateLabel    = setInterval(function() {
        timerEl.innerHTML = secondsPassed + ' seconds'; //update the view every 1 second with the seconds passed.

        var color = 'green';
    
        if( secondsPassed >= 10 ){
            color = 'yellow';
        }
        if( secondsPassed >= 20 ){
            color = 'red';
        }
    
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;

    }, 1000);

startBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  
  clearInterval(secondsTimer); //incase its double clicked
  secondsPassed = 0; //remove this line if you dont want it to reset
  
  secondsTimer = setInterval(function() {
    secondsPassed++; //every 1 second we increase the second count
  }, 1000);
  
});

stopBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  clearInterval(secondsTimer); //when its clicked we just stop the timer
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.wrapper img {
  display: block;
  max-height: 200px;
}
.wrapper span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 25%;
  color: red;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img id="Image1" src="http://s15.postimg.org/es5w3xpob/skull.gif" />
  <span id="timer"></span>
</div>

<button id="start">start</button>
<button id="stop">stop</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, and yes I should of been more clear. For the beginning format it should be no skull, and Start and Stop for buttons. During the countdown it should be the buttons with the countdown going, once it's negative... I'd like the skull to blink every second. You'll see my attempt on my **else** statement. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the image over the buttons, the future solution is to use CSS property `pointer-events: none` but it's still experiental and looks to be part of CSS 4. Use only if it works in your favorite browser and that's good enough. See also [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) and on SO [Pass mouse events through absolutely-positioned element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009753/pass-mouse-events-through-absolutely-positioned-element)

Another solution would be to capture events on a wrapper container and then decide in code if a click event occurred over the start or stop button and call the appropriate handler function if it did so. Suffers from difficulty in getting the browser to respond in normal fashion to mouseover/out events targetting the buttons but the method has been used.

Another solution shown in the example below is to use three layers in the stacking context. Place buttons and countdown elements on the bottom layer. Place the scull and cross bones on the middle layer, and put labels for the buttons, located on the bottom layer, on a top layer. These top `label` elements dispatch (copies of) mouse events to the real buttons without additional script for this action. The labels are hidden and need to be dimensioned and placed carefully.

Working in current versions of Firefox and IE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>skull blink</title><meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">

.centerText
{    text-align: center;
}
#countdown
{   display: inline-block;
    height: 60px;
    width: 350px;
    color:black;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: opacity 0.9s;
}
#countFill /* same size as #countdown */
{   display: inline-block;
    height: 60px;
    width: 350px;
}

div#z0 /*  parent node of #z10 and #z20  */
{   display: inline-block;
}
div#z10
{  display: inline-block;
   position: absolute;
   width: 350px;
   z-index: 10;
   visibility: hidden;
   transition: visibility 0.3s;
}
div#z20
{  display: inline-block;
   position: absolute;
   width: 350px;
   text-align: center;
   z-index: 20;
}
button.dimension /* same size as active start/stop buttons */
{  visibility: hidden;
}
#skullImg
{ height: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
}
</style>
<script>
var seconds = 10;
var countdownTimer = 0;

function startTimer() {
    if(!countdownTimer)
    {  countdownTimer = setInterval(secondPassed, 1000);
       secondPassed();  // start now
    }
}

function stopTimer() {
    clearTimeout(countdownTimer);
    countdownTimer = 0;
    showSkull(false);
}

function showSkull( on) {
    document.getElementById("z10").style.visibility = on ? "visible" : "hidden";
    document.getElementById("countdown").style.opacity = on ? 0 : 1;
}

 function floor(x) {
     return x | 0;
 }

function pad(n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        n = -n;
    }
    if (n < 10) {
        return '0' + n.toString();
    }
     return n.toString();
}

 function secondPassed() {
    var minutes = pad(floor(seconds / 60));
    if (seconds < 0) {
        minutes = '-' + minutes;
    }
    var remainingSeconds = pad(seconds % 60);

    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
    if (seconds > 8) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    } else if (seconds == 5) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    } else if (seconds ==0) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    } else if (seconds < 0) {
        showSkull(seconds & 1) // odd seconds  
    }
    seconds--;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="centerText">
    <div id="z0">
    <div id="z10"><img src="http://s15.postimg.org/es5w3xpob/skull.gif" id="skullImg"></div>
    <div id="z20">
        <span id="countFill">&nbsp;</span><br>
        <label for="start"><button class="dimension">Start</button></label>
        <label for="stop"><button class="dimension">Stop</button></label>
    </div>
        <span id="countdown">&nbsp;</span><br>
        <button id="start" onclick="startTimer()">Start</button>
        <button id="stop" onclick="stopTimer()">Stop</button><br>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```