# AngularJS - Trigger ng-mouseenter of element behind another element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

The `<div>` content inside the `<td>` element can be resized by dragging the bottom the of `<div>` down to the `<td>` below.

The `<td>` element on the other hand, has the ng-mouseenter event that triggers the resizing of the dragged `<div>` content.

**Illustration:**

1) `myDiv` height inherits the size of `<td>` element

```
+-------+
| myDiv |
|   =   |
+-------+
|       |
|       |
+-------+
```

2) When `myDiv` is dragged to the `<td>` element below, the `ng-mouseenter` event of `<td>` is triggered and multiplies the height of my `myDiv` based on the number of `<td>`'s

```
+-------+
| myDiv |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|   =   |
+-------+
```

**The issue:**

Since `myDiv` is resized, and overlaps on top of the `<td>` element, it seems that `myDiv` prevents the `ng-mouseenter` from firing as it resides on top of the element with the event. Thus, the use wont be able to decrease the size of `myDiv`. Is there a way to trigger the event even with element on top of it?

Comment: why you put `<td>` in `div`?it is wrong.

Comment: @Hadi He said `The <div> content inside the <td> element `... you probably misinterpreted.

Comment: When you say "overlapping", do you mean the div has position absolute and is floating above the table?

Comment: @Michael can you please provide a working demo here or on [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Hi @Himanshu, I'm currently working on it. Sorry if I haven't provided one yet

Answer (score 2):

One solution, I guess, would be to set the `pointer-events` in the div to `none` once the drag has started. This would mean the pointer events will pass through the div and should be received by the `td`.

Look here for more: [Pass mouse events through absolutely-positioned element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009753/pass-mouse-events-through-absolutely-positioned-element)