# CSS hover on all overlapping elements

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a simple way to trigger a hover event on all overlapping elements? I'd love to be able to do it with just CSS.

Here is a little example: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tk3rm6pe/)
Basically I have a few rows of divs which will move with the page when I scroll. Then a single overlapping div with it's position set to fixed. Both sets of divs have a CSS:hover event to change their background color so they get highlighted when I mouseover them.

My goal is to make it so that when I mouse over `overlapping` it turns red AND whatever `sample text` div that is behind it turns grey.

The only way I can think of to do this right now is with javascript. And it's inelegant. Basically get the mouse position on the overlapping div, and loop through all the `sample text` divs to check if their position is under the mouse.

Comment: by setting the overlapping divs position to fixed you're removing it from the normal flow of the DOM, this makes achieving what you're after with pure CSS pretty much impossible

Comment: you need javascript to do that

Comment: Pretty much what I figured. But is it at least possible to have a mouseover event triggered for both elements when they overlap? so that I have just put the listeners on all the elements and have a simple function that changes the color?

Comment: any possibility of screenshot with this current behavior ?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to easily do what you are wanting. This seems somewhat related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009753/pass-mouse-events-through-absolutely-positioned-element).

Comment: @Herohtar Yes, I was initially hoping there was a `pointer-events` setting that would do what I want, no such luck.
@Searching There is a jsFiddle of my basic setup in my question.

Comment: Not exactly right, sort of a cheat's way which you may or may not be interested in: https://jsfiddle.net/jennift/tk3rm6pe/1/

Comment: @Jennift clever, though it breaks down when you scroll the page. I'd basically needs to reposition the `.overlap` div on the fly, which would be just as complicated (if not more) than using the mouse position to find overlap.