# Event-bubbling with z-indices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uLap7yeq/19/

**Problem**

Consider two elements, canvas and div, which are on the same tree depth and have the same parent. They are both placed on the same position using CSS however div has the higher z-index. How can you capture events from the div and pass them along to the lower z-index? Do I have to do .dispatchEvent() on the canvas?

EDIT: To clarify, I'd like the div to receive the event, do whatever it wants and then pass it along to the next z-indexed element.

**The JSFiddle pasted inline:**

```js
/*
     How can I pass the event along to #canvas?
    */
$('#container').on('click', function(e) {
  console.log('#container click');
});
$('#canvas').on('click', function(e) {
  console.log('#canvas click');
});
$('#other-div').on('click', function(e) {
  console.log('#other-div click');
});
```

```css
#other-div {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#canvas {
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="other-div">
    <p>
      Something
    </p>
  </div>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: hope this question gets the attention it deserves

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass mouse events through absolutely-positioned element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009753/pass-mouse-events-through-absolutely-positioned-element)

Comment: @sinhavartika this is not a duplicate, read the question carefully

Comment: The words are different, yes. The setup is different: yes. But the crux of the problem is same. Both elements are absolutely positioned. Does not matter in the same tree or not. If you think otherwise. Please let me know where I am wrong.

Comment: @sinhavartika he doesnt want the event to pass through . we want the event to trigger on both element. So the problem is completely different

Comment: @sinhavartika I edited my question slightly (text with prefix EDIT:), would you agree that this is different enough?

Comment: Sure enough! Yes now it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding css property `pointer-events: none;` to the `#other-div` will let clicks or other pointer-related events to pass through the div and reach both the canvas and the container

```
#other-div {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

See [**Fiddle 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/rn81ns7j/)

---

If this is not suitable because you need that the `other-div` too captures the event (as per your comment) then you may trigger programmatically an event on the canvas when the container is clicked

```
$('#container').on('click', function(e) {
  console.log('#container click');
  $('#canvas').click(); // <------
});
$('#canvas').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation(); // <------
  console.log('#canvas click');
});
$('#other-div').on('click', function(e) {
  console.log('#other-div click');
});
```

When the cointainer receives a click then it triggers a click on the undelying canvas too: `$('#canvas').click();`

Note that when the click finally hits the canvas the event must stop propagate, otherwise it will bubble and hit both the `#other-div` and the `#container` leading to an infinite loop. This is why you have `e.stopImmediatePropagation();`

See [**Fiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/0enbjx9j/)

Comment: Hi! I clarified my intent in the question :-). I did want other-div to also capture the event!

Comment: @JohanSjolen that's why i used custom event to avoid the issue of the click event propagation ;) ... also the click event should be triggered when click on the outer div not the container

Answer (score 2):

You can trigger  a [custom event](https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/) when you click on the `outer-div` and make the `canvas` listening to this event:

```js
$('#container').on('click', function(e) {
  console.log('#container click');
});
$('#canvas').on('click custom', function(e) {
  console.log('#canvas click');
});
$('#other-div').on('click', function(e) {
  console.log('#other-div click');
  $('#canvas').trigger( "custom");
});
```

```css
#other-div {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background:rgba(255,0,0,0.2);
}

#canvas {
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background:rgba(255,255,0,0.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="other-div">
  <p>
   Something
  </p>
  </div>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dynamic approach by patching the Element prototype:

```js
if (!document.elementsFromPoint) {
    document.elementsFromPoint = elementsFromPoint;
}

function elementsFromPoint(x, y) {
    var parents = [];
    var parent = void 0;
    do {
        if (parent !== document.elementFromPoint(x, y)) {
            parent = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
            parents.push(parent);
            parent.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
        } else {
            parent = false;
        }
    } while (parent);
    parents.forEach(function (parent) {
        parent.style.pointerEvents = 'initial';
    });
    return parents;
}

Element.prototype.makeEventGoThrough = function(eventName) {
  $(this).on(eventName, (e) => {
    var elements = document.elementsFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    var children = [].slice.call(this.children);
    elements = elements.filter(element => element !== this && !children.find(el => el === element));
    elements.forEach(element => $(element).trigger(eventName));
  });
}


/*
 How can I pass the event along to #canvas?
*/
document.getElementById('other-div').makeEventGoThrough('click');
$('#other-div').on('click', () => console.log('other-div clicked'));
$('#canvas').on('click', () => console.log('canvas clicked'));
```

```css
#other-div {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#canvas {
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="other-div">
  <p>
   Something
  </p>
  </div>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
</div>
```