# Is it possible to carry events (any/all) from canvas to the div beneath the canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, canvas

I have a Canvas on top. Div and its children are below the canvas in terms of z-index.

In the below picture, you see the canvas and its sibling a div with class="o-learnosity".
And canvas is used for scribbling, div has HTML content.

[image]

Now I need a workaround for users should be able to both scribble and interact with html contents like dropdown, inputs, drag and drop, etc same time.

So I thought let me carry the events to div contents from canvas to div.
This is what I have written

Function:

```
this.learnosityC = document.getElementsByClassName('o-learnosity')[0];
this.canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')

this.canvas.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
  console.log('Click on Canvas')
  this.canvas.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
  this.element = document.elementFromPoint(evt.x, evt.y);
  this.element.focus();
  this.element.click(); 
  this.element.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
     this.canvas.style.pointerEvents = 'auto'; 
    });
  });
```

DOM:

```
<div className="a-appView__contents" id="container" >
 <div className="o-learnosity">
   <div id="learnosity_assess">
      Contents here
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Problems with this code:

1. I experimented only with the click events, not sure how to carry all types of events.
2. It works the first time. You can scribble, along with you can click to open the dropdown. Then you can scribble too. Next, you can only scribble but not interact with html elements at all.
3. Is this a correct way of approaching this problem?

I request only a Javascript solution if available. No jQuery. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The current design is problematic for accessibility. Instead, you can offer the user a toggle input that will enable/disable (show/hide) the canvas, and — by doing so — solve the problem that you asked about.

Comment: I wish I could do that. The requirement itself is like that. Both scribbling and interaction should happen at the same time.

Comment: By default events propagate through all overlapping layers - so a click that hits the x/y coordinates of two divs will deliver a click event to both unless you `stopPropagation`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Between a canvas with z-index = 100 and a div with z-index = 1 , default propagation doesn't happen.

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49049829/event-bubbling-with-z-indices